# HTTP Post with ContentURL

Tags: api, http, post, botframework, restsharp

I a using Microsoft Bot Framework and am trying to do a HTTP Post with an image sent to the bot as an attachment. I see a ContentURL in the Attachment object but cannot figure out how to POST the image to my API with RestSharp?

Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you provide your code and state the progress and problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple possibilities here.

First is to send an image as an attachment.  Please see [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-add-media-attachments)  you JSON would look like this:

```
{
    "type": "message",
    "from": {
        "id": "12345678",
        "name": "sender's name"
    },
    "conversation": {
        "id": "abcd1234",
        "name": "conversation's name"
   },
   "recipient": {
        "id": "1234abcd",
        "name": "recipient's name"
    },
    "text": "Here's a picture of the duck I was telling you about.",
    "attachments": [
        {
            "contentType": "image/png",
            "contentUrl": "http://aka.ms/Fo983c",
            "name": "duck-on-a-rock.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "replyToId": "5d5cdc723
}
```

the other possibility is that you could send an image in a card (which has 2 possibilities itself).  For this you can see [this documentation for rich cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-add-rich-cards). in this here is an example of the JSON for that

```
{
    "type": "message",
    "from": {
        "id": "12345678",
        "name": "sender's name"
    },
    "conversation": {
        "id": "abcd1234",
        "name": "conversation's name"
    },
    "recipient": {
        "id": "1234abcd",
        "name": "recipient's name"
    },
    "attachments": [
        {
            "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero",
            "content": {
                "title": "title goes here",
                "subtitle": "subtitle goes here",
                "text": "descriptive text goes here",
                "images": [
                    {
                        "url": "http://aka.ms/Fo983c",
                        "alt": "picture of a duck",
                        "tap": {
                            "type": "playAudio",
                            "value": "url to an audio track of a duck call goes here"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "buttons": [
                    {
                        "type": "playAudio",
                        "title": "Duck Call",
                        "value": "url to an audio track of a duck call goes here"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "openUrl",
                        "title": "Watch Video",
                        "image": "http://aka.ms/Fo983c",
                        "value": "url goes here of the duck in flight"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "replyToId": "5d5cdc723"
}
```

the second option for cards would be [adaptive cards](http://adaptivecards.io/).  by using the [visualizer](http://adaptivecards.io/visualizer/)  you can actually manipulate the JSON and see how it would be rendered in different channels.